# Can anyone help me to create slick drop down using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a horizontal menu like this

[image]

I would like to have slick jquery drop down under profile,settings and notifications.

Can anyone help me to implement it?

Here is my [current jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/TDHvr/1/)

Thanks

Comment: Define "slick". 1st result on the google btw: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: That's a pretty cool looking notification bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i do someting. You can change some style things :)

http://jsfiddle.net/TDHvr/2/